# Liquibase rollback not working with "Liquibase Rollback Successful"

Tags: mysql, liquibase

Please, can you help me with rollback action? It is some kind of magic - liquibase report me about successful rollback action, but nothing change.
We use sql formatted SQL. For example i have 3 files:

CASE-0-1.sql:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset CASE-0-1:1 failOnError:true
CREATE TABLE tt1(
cc1 INT(11));

--rollback DROP TABLE tt1;
--rollback CREATE TABLE tr1(
--rollback cr1 INT(20));
```

CASE-0-2.sql:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset CASE-0-2:1 failOnError:true
CREATE TABLE tt2(
cc2 INT(11));

--rollback DROP TABLE tt2;
--rollback CREATE TABLE tr2(
--rollback cr2 INT(20));
```

CASE-0-3.sql:

```
--liquibase formatted sql

--changeset CASE-0-3:1 failOnError:true
CREATE TABLE tt3(
cc3 INT(11));

--rollback DROP TABLE tt3;
--rollback CREATE TABLE tr3(
--rollback cr3 INT(20));
```

I TAG database before making any changes:

```
/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --logFile=0state.tag.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  tag "0state"
```

After that i apply files and TAG database after each file apply:

```
/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --changeLogFile=CASE-0-1.sql --logFile=CASE-0-1.sql.update.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  update
/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --logFile=CASE-0-1.sql.tag.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  tag "CASE-0-1"

/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --changeLogFile=CASE-0-2.sql --logFile=CASE-0-2.sql.update.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  update
/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --logFile=CASE-0-2.sql.tag.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  tag "CASE-0-2"

/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --changeLogFile=CASE-0-3.sql --logFile=CASE-0-3.sql.update.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  update
/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --logFile=CASE-0-3.sql.tag.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  tag "CASE-0-3"
```

Result:

```
[root@mysql]# mysql -e "SELECT ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, EXECTYPE, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, TAG \
>           FROM DATABASECHANGELOG;" liquibase_test
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
| ID            | AUTHOR    | FILENAME           | DATEEXECUTED        | ORDEREXECUTED | EXECTYPE | DESCRIPTION | COMMENTS | TAG      |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 1506498093527 | liquibase | liquibase-internal | 2017-09-27 10:41:33 |             1 | EXECUTED | empty       |          | 0state   |
| 1             | CASE-0-1  | CASE-0-1.sql       | 2017-09-27 10:41:57 |             2 | EXECUTED | sql         |          | CASE-0-1 |
| 1             | CASE-0-2  | CASE-0-2.sql       | 2017-09-27 10:42:08 |             3 | EXECUTED | sql         |          | CASE-0-2 |
| 1             | CASE-0-3  | CASE-0-3.sql       | 2017-09-27 10:42:12 |             4 | EXECUTED | sql         |          | CASE-0-3 |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
[root@mysql]# mysql -e "SHOW TABLES;" liquibase_test
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_liquibase_test |
+--------------------------+
| DATABASECHANGELOG        |
| DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK    |
| tt1                      |
| tt2                      |
| tt3                      |
+--------------------------+
```

Now, lets try rollback:

```
/root/liquibase/liquibase --logLevel=debug --classpath=/usr/share/java/mysql-connector-java.jar --driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true" \
  --changeLogFile=CASE-0-2.sql --logFile=CASE-0-2.sql.rollback.log --username=trunk --password=Trunk \
  rollback "CASE-0-2"
Liquibase Rollback Successful
```

Looks like all fine, but rollback was not executed:

```
[root@mysql]# mysql -e "SELECT ID, AUTHOR, FILENAME, DATEEXECUTED, ORDEREXECUTED, EXECTYPE, DESCRIPTION, COMMENTS, TAG \
>           FROM DATABASECHANGELOG;" liquibase_test
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
| ID            | AUTHOR    | FILENAME           | DATEEXECUTED        | ORDEREXECUTED | EXECTYPE | DESCRIPTION | COMMENTS | TAG      |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
| 1506498093527 | liquibase | liquibase-internal | 2017-09-27 10:41:33 |             1 | EXECUTED | empty       |          | 0state   |
| 1             | CASE-0-1  | CASE-0-1.sql       | 2017-09-27 10:41:57 |             2 | EXECUTED | sql         |          | CASE-0-1 |
| 1             | CASE-0-2  | CASE-0-2.sql       | 2017-09-27 10:42:08 |             3 | EXECUTED | sql         |          | CASE-0-2 |
| 1             | CASE-0-3  | CASE-0-3.sql       | 2017-09-27 10:42:12 |             4 | EXECUTED | sql         |          | CASE-0-3 |
+---------------+-----------+--------------------+---------------------+---------------+----------+-------------+----------+----------+
[root@mysql]# mysql -e "SHOW TABLES;" liquibase_test
+--------------------------+
| Tables_in_liquibase_test |
+--------------------------+
| DATABASECHANGELOG        |
| DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK    |
| tt1                      |
| tt2                      |
| tt3                      |
+--------------------------+
```

As you can see - same set of tables we have, no table drops, no additional tables was created.

What we have in rollback logfile:

```
[root@mysql]# cat CASE-0-2.sql.rollback.log:
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Connected to trunk2@127.0.0.1@jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Setting auto commit to false from true
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT LOCKED FROM liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK WHERE ID=1
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Lock Database
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'mysql-gigantic-dummy-dvaco-trunk-28.aws.srv (172.29.13.83)', LOCKGRANTED = '2017-09-27 10:53:26.625' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0
INFO 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Successfully acquired change log lock
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Computed checksum for 1506498806750 as 17f1742877fc068db5453ca9db9d60e3
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT MD5SUM FROM liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOG WHERE MD5SUM IS NOT NULL LIMIT 1
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: select count(*) from liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOG
INFO 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Reading from liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOG
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing QUERY database command: SELECT * FROM liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOG ORDER BY DATEEXECUTED ASC, ORDEREXECUTED ASC
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: CASE-0-2.sql: CASE-0-2.sql::1::CASE-0-2: Computed checksum for inputStream as 80fa2b893f3b36ef72cf796a9ce61189
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: CASE-0-2.sql: CASE-0-2.sql::1::CASE-0-2: Computed checksum for 7:80fa2b893f3b36ef72cf796a9ce61189: as 6c11f0a414ae9865f42a220f71f1e3d1
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Release Database Lock
DEBUG 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Executing UPDATE database command: UPDATE liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1
INFO 27.09.17 10:53: liquibase: Successfully released change log lock
```

I checked different variants, different liquibase file formatting, different command line options - useless. Liquibase always say "Liquibase Rollback Successful", but do nothing.

Please, help. May be someone use rollback actions with sql, or other formats? Where the mistake? What i am doing wrong? Is it working liquibase feature at all?

Comment: A guess out of the blue: Put the `SQLs` of your rollbacks on a new line and not on the same line as the `--rollback` itself. (Maybe liquibase tells you that it was successful because there were no SQLs to execute for your rollback.)

Comment: :) I tried to do like you say - in this case liquibase execute statement in same changeset, just like this statement part of changeset, but not part of rollback.

Comment: Have you tried to print rollbackSQL to file/STDOUT?
see [Database Rollback Commands](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/command_line.html)

Comment: Result of rollbackSQL:

Comment: --  *********************************************************************

Comment: --  Rollback to 'CASE-0-2' Script

Comment: --  *********************************************************************

Comment: --  Change Log: CASE-0-2.sql
--  Ran at: 11.10.17 9:43
--  Against: trunk@127.0.0.1@jdbc:mysql://localhost/liquibase_test?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&useSSL=false&autoReconnect=true
--  Liquibase version: 3.5.3

Comment: --  *********************************************************************

Comment: --  Lock Database

Comment: UPDATE liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 1, LOCKEDBY = 'mysql.db (111.111.111.111)', LOCKGRANTED = '2017-10-11 09:43:02.207' WHERE ID = 1 AND LOCKED = 0;

Comment: --  Release Database Lock

Comment: UPDATE liquibase_test.DATABASECHANGELOGLOCK SET LOCKED = 0, LOCKEDBY = NULL, LOCKGRANTED = NULL WHERE ID = 1;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope you are still interested in help, but from what I can tell, you aren't including your CASE-0-3 SQL scripts, so liquibase doesn't know about changes applied beyond the CASE-0-2 tag you supplied - thus it can't roll it back.

What my team has done is instead create a more robust `changelog.xml` that references our .sql scripts instead of using .sql scripts as the changelog file.

Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 3):

I resolved the issue and found it works.  The issue is the following:
During migration/update the --changeLogFile parameter takes file name and finds it in --classpath folder. It then stores the filename with full path in its log table.

However on rollback the same doesn't work.  You need to provide the full path of the file name in --changeLogFile. It just does the compare of this parameter against the log table. It doesn't use the classpath in this case to prep-end to the changeLogFile before doing a search in its log table.

Answer (score 0):

For those who will face with similar issues, here is one of possible causes of the problem:

During rollback liquibase compares given parameters with appropriate parameters from a databasechangelog table.

Imagine we are going to invoke a rollback. And we would like to do that outside of a project directory. So, we have the next command:

```
liquibase --url="some-jdbc-url" --changelog-file="/some/path/to/the/db/changelog/changelog-1.json" --username=someusername --password=somepassword rollback-count 1
```

and also we have the next content in our databasechangelog table:

```
|   id  |   author  |       filename               |      dateexecuted     |orderexecuted|exectype|       md5sum                     |  description   |comments|tag|liquibase|contexts|labels|deployment_id|
|-------|-----------|------------------------------|-----------------------|-------------|--------|----------------------------------|----------------|--------|---|---------|--------|------|-------------|
|some-id|some-author|/db/changelog/changelog-1.json|2022-12-29 10:00:00.000|     1       |EXECUTED|8:2645faaa8ad312262c8dc1111eeeeeee|some-description|        |   |  4.18.0 |        |      | 1112233445  |
```

Please note, that a file name in the table is different (e.g. because changelogs were invoked within a project directory during a startup)

So, in this case rollback will not have an effect although `Liquibase command 'rollback-count' was executed successfully` is printed.

**It happens because provided changelog path in the rollback command and a path in the table are not equal**:
(`/some/path/to/the/db/changelog/changelog-1.json` and `/db/changelog/changelog-1.json`).

**They must be equal**

To fix that problem we need to go to the appropriate directory, so our path to the changelog becomes the same. In our example we should go to `/some/path/to/the` and invoke next command:

```
liquibase --url="some-jdbc-url" --changelog-file="/db/changelog/changelog-1.json" --username=someusername --password=somepassword rollback-count 1
```

Now, since `--changelog-file` value and `filename` value are equal, rollback makes changes.

**So, during your investigtions please put attention on parameters matching (between provided in a command and in a databasechangelog table). Check provided changelog path, calculated checksums, authors and so on.**